# PortAudio microphone capture, separate channel values

Tags: c, audio, core-audio, microphone, portaudio

I'm using a microphone array (playstation eye) with PortAudio. I'm attempting microphone array processing where I can know the level of each microphone and specify the direction of a sound using beam forming or inter aural time delays. I'm having trouble determining which sound levels come from each channel.

Here is some code snippets, the first being the recordCallback.

```
static int recordCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                          unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                          const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                          PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                          void *userData )
{

    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;


    const SAMPLE *rptr = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    SAMPLE *wptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex * NUM_CHANNELS];
    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    (void) outputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) timeInfo;
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    if( framesLeft < framesPerBuffer )
    {
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        framesToCalc = framesPerBuffer;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    if( inputBuffer == NULL )
    {
        for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* 1 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS =>= 2 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* 2 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS =>= 3 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* 3 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS >= 4 ) *wptr++ = SAMPLE_SILENCE;  /* 4 */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for( i=0; i<framesToCalc; i++ )
        {
            *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* 1 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS >= 2 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* 2 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS >= 3 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* 3 */
            if( NUM_CHANNELS >= 4 ) *wptr++ = *rptr++;  /* 4 */
        }
    }
    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}
```

Here is the main method where I'm playing back the audio and trying to show channel averages.

```
int main(void)
{
    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters,
    outputParameters;
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err = paNoError;
    paTestData          data;
    int                 i;
    int                 totalFrames;
    int                 numSamples;
    int                 numBytes;
    SAMPLE              max, val;
    double              average;

    printf("patest_record.c\n"); fflush(stdout);

    data.maxFrameIndex = totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE; /* Record for a few seconds. */
    data.frameIndex = 0;
    numSamples = totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;
    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    data.recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes ); /* From now on, recordedSamples is initialised. */
    if( data.recordedSamples == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ ) data.recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    inputParameters.device = 2; /* default input device */
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default input device.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    inputParameters.channelCount = 2;                    /* stereo input */
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    /* Record some audio. -------------------------------------------- */
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
                        &stream,
                        &inputParameters,
                        NULL,                  /* &outputParameters, */
                        SAMPLE_RATE,
                        FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                        paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
                        recordCallback,
                        &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;
    printf("\n=== Now recording!! Please speak into the microphone. ===\n"); fflush(stdout);

    while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 )
    {
        Pa_Sleep(1000);

        printf("index = %d\n", data.frameIndex ); fflush(stdout);
        printf("Channel = %d\n", data.currentChannel ); fflush(stdout);
    }
    if( err < 0 ) goto done;

    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    /* Measure maximum peak amplitude. */

    /*  average for each channel */

    SAMPLE channel1val =0;
    SAMPLE channel2val = 0;
    SAMPLE channel3val =0;
    SAMPLE channel4val = 0;

    long channel1avg = 0.0;
    long channel2avg =0.0;
    long channel3avg =0.0;
    long channel4avg =0.0;

    SAMPLE channel1max = 0;
    SAMPLE channel2max =0;
    SAMPLE channel3max =0;
    SAMPLE channel4max =0;

    i = 0;
    do
    {

        channel1val = data.recordedSamples[i];
        if (channel1val < 0)
        {
            channel1val = -channel1val;
        }

        if (channel1val > channel1max)
        {
            channel1max = channel1val;
        }
        channel1avg  += channel1val;

        i = i + 4;
    }
    while (i<numSamples);

    i = 1;
    do
    {
        channel2val = data.recordedSamples[i];
        if (channel2val < 0)
        {
            channel2val = -channel2val;
        }

        if (channel2val > channel2max)
        {
            channel2max = channel2val;
        }
        channel2avg  += channel2val;

        i = i + 4;
    }
    while (i<numSamples);

    i = 2;
    do
    {
        channel3val = data.recordedSamples[i];
        if (channel3val < 0)
        {
            channel3val = -channel3val;
        }

        if (channel3val > channel3max)
        {
            channel3max = channel3val;
        }
        channel3avg  += channel3val;

        i = i + 4;
    }
    while (i<numSamples);

    i = 3;
    do
    {
        channel4val = data.recordedSamples[i];
        if (channel4val < 0)
        {
            channel4val = -channel4val;
        }

        if (channel4val > channel4max)
        {
            channel4max = channel4val;
        }
        channel4avg  += channel4val;

        i = i + 4;
    }
    while (i<numSamples);






    channel1avg = channel1avg / (double)numSamples;
    channel2avg = channel2avg / (double)numSamples;
    channel3avg = channel3avg / (double)numSamples;
    channel4avg = channel4avg / (double)numSamples;

  // printf("sample max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", max );
  //  printf("sample average = %lf\n", average );


    printf("channel1 max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", channel1max);
    printf("sample average = %lf\n", channel1avg);

    printf("channel2 max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", channel2max);
    printf("sample average = %lf\n", channel2avg);

    printf("channel3 max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", channel3max);
    printf("sample average = %lf\n", channel3avg);

    printf("channel4 max amplitude = "PRINTF_S_FORMAT"\n", channel4max);
    printf("sample average = %lf\n", channel4avg);


    printf("/nPrinting out values/n");

    for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        printf("Value: %lf\n", data.recordedSamples[j]);
    }


    /* Write recorded data to a file. */
#if WRITE_TO_FILE
    {
        FILE  *fid;
        fid = fopen("recorded.raw", "wb");
        if( fid == NULL )
        {
            printf("Could not open file.");
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite( data.recordedSamples, NUM_CHANNELS * sizeof(SAMPLE), totalFrames, fid );
            fclose( fid );
            printf("Wrote data to 'recorded.raw'\n");
        }
    }
#endif

    /* Playback recorded data.  -------------------------------------------- */
    data.frameIndex = 0;

    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default output device.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    outputParameters.channelCount = 2;                     /* stereo output */
    outputParameters.sampleFormat =  PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    printf("\n=== Now playing back. ===\n"); fflush(stdout);
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
                        &stream,
                        NULL, /* no input */
                        &outputParameters,
                        SAMPLE_RATE,
                        FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                        paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
                        playCallback,
                        &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

    if( stream )
    {
        err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

        printf("Waiting for playback to finish.\n"); fflush(stdout);

        while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 ) Pa_Sleep(100);
        if( err < 0 ) goto done;

        err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
        if( err != paNoError ) goto done;

        printf("Done.\n"); fflush(stdout);
    }

done:
    Pa_Terminate();
    if( data.recordedSamples )       /* Sure it is NULL or valid. */
        free( data.recordedSamples );
    if( err != paNoError )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
        fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
        err = 1;          /* Always return 0 or 1, but no other return codes. */
    }
    return err;
}
```

If I run my code and blow into one microphone I get this. When I play the sound back using my code, it works fine and the sound is correct, but looking at the values outputted:

```
channel1 max amplitude = 1.00000000
sample average = 1.000000
channel2 max amplitude = 0.02542114
sample average = 0.025421
channel3 max amplitude = 1.00000000
sample average = 1.000000
channel4 max amplitude = 0.02627563
sample average = 0.026276
```

Which clearly isn't correct. As it's showing that two channels are almost identical. From what I understand, as it's capturing linear PCM, it should be mapping channels such as

SAMPLE
[
{Channel1}
{Channel2}
{Channel3}
{Channel4}
]

Now the problem is, when I blow into one microphone on audacity (which uses core-audio drivers) I get this. Clearly one microphone has peak of 1 and the others are near silent.

[image: Audacity Levels]

So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, any pointers?

Comment: It looks like you found a solution, but I think I found an issue with your record thread.  If I read your logic correctly you throw away new data if there isn't enough room in your buffer.  Given your use case I'd suggest flushing old data out of your buffer instead of dropping data from the portaudio buffer.  It also looks like your not reading all the samples.  I think you need to read NUM_CHANNELS * frames per buffer samples to get all the samples, but double check the documentation on that one.

Comment: I accepted the solution below as it fixed the error in terms of not seeing 2 channel values but yes I'm still having issues with this program. I'm not sure what you mean though, could you explain further? I followed the example that portaudio gives http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record_8c_source.html

Comment: One second read it looks like the thread terminates when the user buffer is full.  I was assuming you'd want this application to run indefinitely.   If that is the case it would be better to throw away old data that had been queued up rather than drop the new data just read from the mic.

Comment: I do eventually want to run the application indefinitely, ideally I want to record continuously or at least inside a loop and then do some processing when the levels are above a certain threshold. But I wasn't sure how to best go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are only recording 2 channels

```
inputParameters.channelCount = 2;                    /* stereo input */
```

This would explain why ch 1 and 3, and ch 2 and 4 are measuring the same level because you're just skipping every other sample from the same channel.